# What is most readable way to do assert.fail() with should.js

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, assertions, should.js

As Should.js use BDD style of assertions, it suppose to be readable from the code. I am wondering what is the most readable assert.fail() equivalent for should.js. I am missing something like `should.fail`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should.fail exists as a method:

```
should.fail()
```

Comment: Just tried it, such function without parameters doesn't exist, so it fails, but the message is confusing.

Comment: Yeah, that's funny. Guess it's not documented (and doesn't work as I thought), yet it always did the trick for me just by blowing up the test.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED

How about:

- "This should fail".should.be.true;

Comment: There shouldn't be variables. I meant something that fails when that statement is reached.

Comment: Still not ideal from readability point of view, but give you upvote.

Answer (score 0):

So far I came up with:

```
false.should.be.true;
```

or

```
false.should.be.ok;
```